# How to disable items in a combobox in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

How can I disable specific items in a combobox in Ext JS?

For example I have these records

```
row_1_type_1
row_2_type_2
row_3_type_3
```

and I want to disable the third row i.e it should stay in the combo as label but it will be greyed out and not clickable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solutions that you can use at least for Ext JS 4.2.1. It's a plugin that disables some items in the boundlist based on the value of each record. The name of the field to check if the listitem should be disabled can be configured.

Let's start with how to use the plugin.

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    fieldLabel: 'My combo with disabled items',
    valueField: 'value',
    displayField: 'display',
    queryMode: 'local',
    store: {
        fields: ['value', 'display', 'disabled'],
        data: [{
            value: 1, display: 'an enabled item', disabled: false
        },{
            value: 2, display: 'a disabled item', disabled: true
        }]
    },
    plugins: [{
        ptype: 'comboitemsdisableable',
        disabledField: 'disabled'
    }]
}
```

And here's the plugin.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.plugin.ComboItemsDisableable', {
    extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
    alias: 'plugin.comboitemsdisableable',

    init: function (cmp) {
        var me = this; // the plugin
        me.disabledField = me.disabledField || 'disabled';

        cmp.tpl = Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<tpl for=".">',
            '  <tpl if="this.isDisabled(' + me.disabledField + ')">',
            '    <div class="x-boundlist-item x-item-disabled"><em>{' + cmp.displayField + '}</em></div>',
            '  <tpl else>',
            '    <div class="x-boundlist-item">{' + cmp.displayField + '}</div>',
            '  </tpl>',
            '</tpl>', {
                isDisabled: function(disabled) {
                    return disabled;
                }
            }
        );

        // make sure disabled items are not selectable
        cmp.on('beforeselect', function(combo, record, index) {
            return !record.get(me.disabledField);
        });
    }
});
```

And here's some css to go with the plugin. It greys out the disabled items and makes sure that the disabled items when hovered don't get its background changed as to suggest that it would be selectable.

```
.x-item-disabled.x-boundlist-item {
    color: #8c8c8c;
    cursor: default;
}

.x-item-disabled.x-boundlist-item-over {
    background: inherit;
    border-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this with the [`listConfig`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig):

```
myItems: [
    { name: 'row_1_type_1',  disabled: false},
    { name: 'row_2_type_2',  disabled: false},
    { name: 'row_3_type_3',  disabled: true }
]

listConfig: {
    getInnerTpl: function(displayField) {
        return Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<ul><li role="option"',
            '<tpl for=".">',
            '<tpl if="disabled == true">',
                'class="x-disabled-item"',
            '<tpl else>',
                'class="x-custom-item"',
            '</tpl>',
            '>{#} - {name}</li></ul>'
        );
    }
}

//CSS
.x-disabled-item
{
}

.x-custom-item
{
}
```

You can find more about [templates in the docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate)

Comment: Any other much more simple solution? Can i use extjs API to do this?

Comment: What should be "disabled"? Do you mean disabled = "disabled" attribute. Why do I get divs in dom for the combo box instead of ul, il, option etc??

Comment: I am seeing [object Object] when i scroll the combo box. What to do to get the labels instead?

Comment: I guess this will work fo changing the font color to grey if disabled is true, but will it actiually disable the field, so that I cannot click on it at all?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Ext6

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['abbr', 'name', 'disabled'],
            data: [{
                "abbr": "AL",
                "name": "Alabama",
                "disabled": '',
            }, {
                "abbr": "AK",
                "name": "Alaska",
                "disabled": 'x-item-disabled',
            }, {
                "abbr": "AZ",
                "name": "Arizona",
                "disabled": '',
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
            store: states,
            queryMode: 'local',
            valueField: 'abbr',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            // Template for the dropdown menu.
            // Note the use of the "x-list-plain" and "x-boundlist-item" class,
            // this is required to make the items selectable.
            tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for=".">',
                '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item {disabled}">{abbr} - {name}</li>',
                '</tpl></ul>'
            ),
            // template for the content inside text field
            displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<tpl for=".">',
                '{abbr} - {name}',
                '</tpl>'
            )
        });

    }
});
```

Try code here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor

Answer (score 1):

Very tricky example by ordman and a bit complicated by Christiaan.
You can use my simpler example as an alternative.

It is supposed usually that disabled param comes from backend in boolean value, so you need to make some calculations on it.

By the way adding *x-item-disabled* class makes an item unchoosable. If you need just point out disabled item with the ability to choose, I use small part of inline style, so you dont need touch css classes.

Also you can use conditions and operate with all record data by adding function to Ext.XTemplate.

Here is [working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3qng) for 7.6 and 6.6:

```
   Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
        store: states,
        queryMode: 'local',
        valueField: 'abbr',
        displayField: 'name',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for=".">',
                '{[this.getItemTpl(values)]}',
            '</tpl></ul>',
            {
                getItemTpl: function(itm) {
                    const colorStyle = (itm.isActive) ? '' : 'style="color:grey"';
                    // uncomment disabledCls to make item unchoosable
                    //const disabledCls = (itm.isActive) ? '' : 'x-item-disabled';
                    return `<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item ${disabledCls}" ${colorStyle}> ${itm.abbr} - ${itm.name}</li>`;
                }
            }
        )
    });
```