# How to disable a particular data in the combo-box in ExtJS 4.2.1

Tags: javascript, extjs

How do I disable a particular data item in a combo-box in ExtJS 4.2.1? The 
combo-box values are data and value pairs:

```
orderTypes = [
    ['Local', 'Local'],
    ['Device', 'Device'],
    ['None', 'None']
];
```

I want to disable the value 'Device' in the combo-box. So I used tried the code below, where `orderComboTwo` is my comboxbox. However it is not disabling the data listed in the combo-box.

```
 orderComboTwo.getStore().data.items[1].data.disabled = true;
```

Comment: Please check this link if this is what you 
needed.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827828/how-to-disable-items-in-a-combobox-in-ext-js>

Comment: Hi sreenath,its seems they are specific to the field.but my question is, i have two combo box with same values with both the combo box say(local,device and None) in both..Now i have selected "Local" in the first combo box , then i should not able to select the "Local" in the second combo box.probably a dynamic one. what i tried 'listeners: {
 beforeselect: function(combo, records, eOpts) {
  if (records.data.value == orderComboOne.getValue()) {  orderComboTwo.getStore().data.items[1].data.disabled = true;}',the disable = true is not working.it is a second combo-box listener. @SreenathPG

Comment: I think what you are looking for is really difficult to handle and also not possible with the code that you wrote because there is no "disabled" property to a data item of the store. I would suggest if you could do validation if the same value is selected as that of first combobox and hence do not allow the user to proceed with it or else you can directly remove the data or value that has been selected from the first combobox from the second combobox store itself whenever the value is selected in first combobox. It will be a better solution. what do you think?

Comment: @HarshitShah I think removing the data from the second combo-box will not be better, because first thing the can select first time with one value in the first combo-box as "Local" then im removing the same value in the second combo-box, user mind may change with the first combo-box value so that he can go with "Device" now i have to delete the same value in the second combo-box.now the value in the second combo-box will be only "None". Hope you understand the difficulty in removing the value in the second combo-box.

Comment: No.. I meant whenever you select a value in first combo, you just reload the second combostore with removal of only the first combo selected value.

Comment: removal is working, but im in need of disable the item @HarshitShah

Comment: Sorry in that case I don't know any such solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

A `ComboBox` does not have the possibility to disable certain entries by default.

However, it has the `beforeselect`  event which you can use to tell the combobox whether a certain value may be selected or not, depending e.g. on the currently selected value of another combobox:

```
[{
    xtype:'combo',
    listeners:{
        beforeselect:function(cb, record) {
            if(cb.nextSibling().getSelection().indexOf(record) > -1) return false;
        }
    },
},{
    xtype:'combo',
    listeners:{
        beforeselect:function(cb, record) {
            if(cb.previousSibling().getSelection().indexOf(record) > -1) return false;
        }
    }
}]
```

And of course you can always override the `ComboBox` to add the possibility to disable certain items based on a boolean model field:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.ux.DisableCombo',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    xtype:'disablecombo',
    disabledItemCls: 'disabledListItem',
    disabledField: 'disabled',
    onBeforeSelect: function(list, record, recordIndex) {
        if(record.get(this.disabledField)) return false;
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        if(!me.listConfig) me.listConfig = {};
        Ext.apply(me.listConfig, {
            tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<ul class="' + Ext.plainListCls + '"><tpl for=".">',
                    '<li role="option" unselectable="on" class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'boundlist-item' + '<tpl if="' + me.disabledField + '"> ' + me.disabledItemCls + '</tpl>">{' + me.displayField + '}' + '</li>',
                '</tpl></ul>'
            )
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

I have [made a fiddle for you](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1u61) to see it in action.

Comment: your code is working for disabling a particular item in a combo-box,now considering there are two combo-box ,all the values are not disable in combo box 1....based on the selection i made in combo-box 1 i need to disable the value in combo-box 2.you got me?

Comment: @NarenSathya I amended my fiddle for you. I thought that you could do that basic task by yourself with the building blocks I provided.

Comment: I dont think that is a basic task...Actually i have solved this problem using your code only..but its took more time for me to solve this issue..may be you can share your idea or that task, so i can learn and use that how you are disabling the item in combo-box2 using the combo-box1 selection